# Unable to send a WhatsApp message programatically

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to send WhatsApp messages programatically using the following code.

```
void openWhatsappContact(String number, Context context) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + number);
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
        i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "test");
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, ""));
    }
```

This helper function is successfully called everytime (I checked by logging them), but fails to send a message. Apparently it's all going wrong at startActivity (from the logs). Posting the Log for reference.

```
10-20 15:59:34.029: W/System.err(16336): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
10-20 15:59:34.029: W/System.err(16336):    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:847)
10-20 15:59:34.029: W/System.err(16336):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:276)
10-20 15:59:34.029: W/System.err(16336):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:276)
10-20 15:59:34.029: W/System.err(16336):    at com.scimet.admin.driveon.RejectCall.openWhatsappContact(RejectCall.java:79)
10-20 15:59:34.029: W/System.err(16336):    at com.scimet.admin.driveon.RejectCall.onReceive(RejectCall.java:63)
10-20 15:59:34.029: W/System.err(16336):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2139)
10-20 15:59:34.029: W/System.err(16336):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:127)
10-20 15:59:34.029: W/System.err(16336):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1208)
10-20 15:59:34.029: W/System.err(16336):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-20 15:59:34.029: W/System.err(16336):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-20 15:59:34.029: W/System.err(16336):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
10-20 15:59:34.029: W/System.err(16336):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-20 15:59:34.029: W/System.err(16336):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-20 15:59:34.029: W/System.err(16336):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-20 15:59:34.029: W/System.err(16336):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-20 15:59:34.029: W/System.err(16336):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add -

```
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: Done. Working now. Anyways, the intention was to send a message. But all that happens is the chat box opens up. How do I get the message typed and sent programatically?

Comment: Using above method you will get window opened for particular person,but you can't add text there.& if you want to use selected text by using Gaurav's answer you can send it but you have to select person in whatsapp window

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
try {

        Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        String text = "YOUR TEXT HERE";

        PackageInfo info=pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        //Check if package exists or not. If not then code 
        //in catch block will be called
        intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share with"));

   } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
   }
```